# difference between different scenarios of async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

What is the difference between the following scenarios:

**scenario 1 - async-await in axios request - DOES NOT WORK**

```
export const getAll = async () => {
    const retrievedData = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes'); // should return - Array
    return retrievedData.data;
};


const test = () => {
        let anecdotes = getAll();
        // do something 
    };
```

**Scenario 2 - async-await in helper method DOES NOT WORK**

```
export const getAll = () => {
    const retrievedData = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes'); // should return - Array
    return retrievedData.data;
};


const test = async () => {
        let anecdotes = await getAll();
        // do something 
    };
```

**Scenario 3 - async-await in both WORKS**

```
export const getAll = async() => {
    const retrievedData = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes'); // should return - Array
    return retrievedData.data;
};


const test = async () => {
        let anecdotes = await getAll();
        // do something 
    };
```

What is the difference between the above scenarios? **Why does only 3rd case work??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does only 3rd case work??

All `async` functions return a promise - always.   When you `return` a value in an  `async` function, that value becomes the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function returns.

In addition, `axios()` returns a promise so you also need to use `.then()` or `await` on its return value to get the result from the `axios()` call too.

**Scenario 1**

In scenario 1,  Your `getAll()` function is `async` and returns a promise.  Then your `test()` function doesn't use `await` or `.then()` on that promise:

```
const test = () => {
        let anecdotes = getAll();
        // do something 
};
```

Therefore `anecdotes` is just a promise and you haven't actually gotten the value out of the promise.  You need to use `await` or `.then()` on that promise to get the value.

---

**Scenario 2**

Scenario 2 has a slightly different problem.  In `getAll()`you do this:

```
export const getAll = () => {
    const retrievedData = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes');
    return retrievedData.data;
}
```

`axios.get()` returns a promise.  So, `retrievedData` is a promise.  It's not the result you want.  When you `return retrievedData.data`, you're just returning a non-existing property of the promise so it will always return `undefined`.

---

**Scenario 3**

In scenario 3, you do successfully use `await` on the result of the `async` function and on the result of the `axios()` call and thus it works.

```
export const getAll = async() => {
    const retrievedData = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes'); // should return - Array
    return retrievedData.data;
};


const test = async () => {
    let anecdotes = await getAll();
    // do something 
};
```

Comment: `await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/anecdotes');` why isn't the following line not pausing execution until the promise is resolved or rejected?

Comment: @lynxx - It suspends the internal execution of the function, but at the moment it starts the `axios()` function, the `await` tells JS to immediately return a promise from that function and the outside world continues.  Then, when the `axios()` promise resolves, the function resumes again and then when it eventually does a `return`, that sets the resolved value of the promise that has already been returned.  The important thing to understand here is that `await` only suspends the internal execution of the function, not the rest of your code flow.

Comment: @lynxx - At the point of the first `await`, the function returns a promise and the subsequent caller continues to execute.  That's WHY the caller must use `await` or `.then()` on the result of the `async` function because the function a promise returns BEFORE the value is known.  Only when that promise resolves will the value be known. So, `await` only pauses INSIDE the function.  `await` does not stop everything in your code flow.  It only stops the execution of the `async` function it's in and, at that point, it immediately returns a promise.